# Heroku || Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my first node project to heroku but i'm getting this error:

```
2020-09-29T04:24:09.365962+00:00 app[web.1]: production
2020-09-29T04:24:09.415266+00:00 app[web.1]: server is listening at port 40890
2020-09-29T04:24:09.942808+00:00 app[web.1]: DB connection succesfull
2020-09-29T04:25:03.400919+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-09-29T04:25:03.433351+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-09-29T04:25:03.559247+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-09-29T04:25:03.607404+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I'm using express and mongodb.here's the code i'm using :

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });
const app = require('./app');


require('dotenv').config();

const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace(
  '<PASSWORD>',
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);

mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
  })
  .then(con => {
    console.log('DB connection succesfull');
  });


const PORT = process.env.PORT | 3000;

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server is listening at port ${PORT}`);
});
```

how to solve this issue?Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is the issue wrong port use it like this

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

Your server started on wrong PORT number thus on system check it was not able to see your app bind on correct port